# Find the fourth term of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is a question I found in a grade 7 math book...

Chose the correct number to the blank

9, 4, 10, 11, ...... , 26

(a) 16
(b) 18
(c) 24
(d) 32

Thanks

Comment: Thank you but this is in grade 7 math book they don't know Lagrange interpolation right?

Comment: There is no matching sequence at oeis.org.

Comment: But try adding any two consecutive terms, and comparing the sum to the next term.

Comment: It's fun trying to solve this thinking it's valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't any arithmetic, or geometric progression as you would expect. It's rather a simple sequence following the pattern:

$$T_n  + T_{n+1} - 3 = T_{n+2} $$

Therefore,

$T_5$ = $T_3 + T_4 - 3 = 10 + 11 - 3 = 18 $